# Multivariate Normal Distribution of form AZ + a, where Z is normal random vector

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution

Here is the problem:

[image]

I am interested in problem b.

So, my idea is the following: We know, that if $X = AZ + a$, where $ A$ is $m*m$ and $a$ is constant, than $X \sim N(A\mu + a,A\Sigma A^T)$

I want to use this fact and we have two equalities: $$ A\mu + a = 0$$ $$A\Sigma A^T = I$$

And my question is: am I on the right way to solution(i need to find A and a)?
If no, give me a hint please. If yes, how can i derive A from the second equality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

When $m = 1$ the proper transformation is

$$
\frac{Z - \mu}{\sigma} =  \sigma^{-1} Z - \sigma^{-1} \mu.
$$

Since $\Sigma = \sigma^2$ in this case, what does that tell you about $A$ and $a$?  Can you now generalize this for $m \geq 1$?

Comment: Write $A$ in terms of $\Sigma$ using the fact that $\Sigma$ is just a scalar equal to $\sigma^2$, this should make this part of the answer clear.  Then use the fact that $\text{E}(AZ) = A \mu$.

Comment: So, my answer is wrong?

Comment: I didn't really follow your last comment, but it's not true that $A = 1$.  Just try to apply what I said above.

Comment: A! I got it. $A = 1/{\sigma}$ and $a = -{\mu}/{\sigma}$
It was SO obvious, but sometimes such things is't visible.
Thought, it would harder problem.

Comment: Right, now how would you state this in terms of $\Sigma$ and $\mu$, and can you verify the matrix calculations?

Comment: A = $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ amd a = $-\mu \Sigma^{-1/2}$

Comment: Correct, so long as $\Sigma^{-1/2} \Sigma \Sigma^{-1/2} = I$, which still needs to be demonstrated.

Comment: Thank you for the help. 
It seems easy, but...not so:)